# Kio estas la diferenco inter "imponi" kaj "impresi"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Bonvolu klarigi tion al mi, kio estas la diferenco inter:

*Vi imponas min.*
*Vi impresas min.*

Ĉu vi povas aldone krei taŭgan kuntekston por ambaū frazoj?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"*impresi*" havas pli ĝeneralan signifon ol "*imponi*": Dum "*impresi*" simple signifas 'efiki sur la menso aŭ sentumoj', "*imponi*" havas la pli specifan signifon 'kaŭzi respekton aŭ admiron'.

Do oni povas diri "*la akcidento forte impresis lin*" aŭ "*lia aserto impresas kiel paradokso*", sed ne havas sencon uzi "*imponi*" en ĉi tiuj frazoj, ĉar ne temas pri kaŭzado de respekto aŭ admiro.

Anstataŭe, "*imponi*" estas uzata en frazoj kiel "*pro sia ŝajna kompetenteco li imponis al la simpluloj*". Se oni uzus "*impresi*" anstataŭ "*imponi*" en ĉi tiu frazo, oni ne esprimus malimplice ke la *simpluloj* admiris aŭ respektis lin (kvankam tio ja povus esti implicita el la kunteksto, do ne nepre estas malbone uzi "*impresi*" en ĉi tiu frazo, se oni ne volas aparte emfazi la admiron/respekton).

---

"*impresi*" has a more general meaning than "*imponi*": While "*impresi*" just means 'to affect in mind or feelings', "*imponi*" has the more specific meaning 'to cause respect or admiration'.

So you can say "*la akcidento forte impresis lin*" or "*lia aserto impresas kiel paradokso*", but it doesn't make much sense to use "*imponi" in these sentences, as they are not about causing respect or admiration.

Instead, "*imponi*" is used in sentences like "*pro sia ŝajna kompetenteco li imponis al la simpluloj*". If you used "*impresi*" instead of "*imponi*" in this sentence, you wouldn't explicitly say that the *simpluloj* were admiring or respecting him (though it might still be infered from the context, so it's not necessarily bad to use "*impresi*" in this sentence, if you don't want to explicitly stress this admiration/respect).

Comment: Do, cxu *impresi* = angla *to give an impression* kaj *imponi* = angla *to impress*?

Comment: Jes, almenaŭ pli-malpli.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the actual evidence of usage on the tekstaro.com site, it seems that *impres-* is predominantly used as a noun. As in, *Li havis impreson*, or *Ĉi tiu okazo faris malbonan impreson sur la altranguloj.* for example. The number of verbal uses is a lot smaller.

With *impon-* we get a slightly different picture: this is mainly used as an adjective, or an adverb, very rarely as a verb, and practically not at all as a noun. Examples are *La plej impona konstruaĵo de Šiluva,...* or *Efektive, la vidaĵo estis impona.*

Assuming the text collection reflects current usage, then we can conclude that their meaning is very similar (though *impreso* is more a general idea or view/opinon, while *impona* refers to something impressive) but the usage within a sentence is different. If you want to talk about an *impression*, you would say *impreso*, something that is impressive would be *impona*, and if someone *impresses* you, you'd use *imponas*.

The usage reminds me a bit of the German *Impression*/*Eindruck*, which would be like *impreso*, and the verb *imponieren*, which would be like *imponi*. This distinction does not exist in English.

Comment: As I explain in my answer, there is a significant difference in meaning between "*impresi*" and "*imponi*". The difference in frequency of the different word forms is due to this difference in meaning. But it is too simplistic to just decide on which word root to use depending on whether you are going to use a noun, verb or adjective. In order to correctly use these words in Esperanto, one has to understand the difference in meaning between them. See my answer for a clarification.

Comment: @MarcosCramer I was obviously not clear enough in my explanation: I used the distribution of word classes to tease out the difference in meaning. Of course it is not enough to simply look at word classes, but I hope you can see how the word class usage corresponds to the difference in meaning. It is a well-established principle in linguistics that there is a correspondence between form/usage and meaning.

Answer (score 1):

- Imponi = Trudi al iu cedeman respekton, obeeman admiron pro sia supereco
- Impresi = Estigi, fari impreson sur

http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/